# Insert NULL into a nullable row, using $$ in postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I was working on securing my application:

```
q = "insert into foo (name, descr, some_fk_int) values ($${}$$, $${}$$, $${}$$);".format(
  name.replace("$$",""),
  description.replace("$$",""),
  str(fkToAnotherTable).replace("$$","") if fkToANotherTable is not None else 'NULL'
)
cur.execute(q)
```

I noticed that when doing this it will try to insert the string NULL into the DB into an integer entry.  For the sake of keeping things uniform, I was pretty much taking all strings processing it this way, and all ints converting to a string and then doing it as well (just covering bases).

It was working when it was just:

```
.... ($$Tony$$,$$Bar$$, NULL)
```

but now that it is:

```
.....($$Tony$$, $$Bar$$, $$NULL$$)
```

it fails.  I was thinking that there was a way to implement this in a uniform fashion.  I was doing this because when doing lookups on indexes, i noticed that it understood ints as strings

```
select * from foo where id = $$id$$
```

So i was blanketing the app where user input was going to be put into databases.  I could remove it from ints, but I thought this would be smart in case someone tried to pass a string into an int to see "what would happen".

I was thinking that the query would fail if the ID was an int and you did:

```
 select * from foo where id = $$hello$$
```

but i was thinking of more interesting cases where someone would try sqlinjection

```
 select * from foo where id = $$$$ or 1=1$$$$
```

where the injected string was: `$$ or 1=1$$`.  I was thinking that i could resolve it by casting to a string, and then replacing key characters.  BUT in the process of injecting or selects, I was noticing the NULL case, and was trying to figure out how to Bypass it?

Maybe I should customise the query to do something like:

```
q = "insert into foo (name, description, fk) values
  ( $${}$$, $${}$$, {} );".format(
  name.replace("$$",""),
  description.replace("$$",""),
  "$${}$$".format(str(FK).replace("$$","")) if FK is not None else "NULL"
)
```

instead which only adds `$$` if it is NOT None?  Then it would work.

TLDR: Is there a property way to pass 'NULL' into an int field and it understand it as null?

*Edit*:  It seems like people were thinking I should follow parameterized query defintions done in psycopg2 under the Cursor's execute function's second property.

I was not sure sure if it would solve SQL injection, but i was thinking of doing something as follows:

```
q = "select * from foo where name in ({}) and user_id = %s".format(
  ",".join(["%s" for d in my_list])
) 
# creates: select * from foo where name in (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s) and user_id = %s;
args = [d for d in my_list] + [user_id]
# creates [1,2,3,4,5,7493]
cursor.execute(q, args)
```

as the website allows the second argument to be a sequence, list, or dict.

Comment: You want to use prepared statements.

Comment: The best way to avoid sql injection is using prepared statements

Comment: I was looking at the execute function which allowed me to do something like: `cursor.execute("insert into foo (a,b) values(%{}s, %{}s)", ("foo", "bar"))` but some bulk inserts where I need to build the list of values made me unsure if the props passed into the parameters is super dynamic. I was building the contents in `(....)` dynamically.
Guess i could just dynamically append on paren blocks based on the size i need.

Comment: Will prepared statements just auto sanitize?  I wasnt sure if there was something additional i needed to do in conjunction with using prepared statements

Comment: I'm not sure how prepared statements would help here, but I'd encourage you to let psycopg2 do escaping of parameters, see e.g. http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

Comment: @SamMason does the argments need to be a tuple, or can i pass a list into it?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I thought [prepared statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html) explicitly had `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` statements.  I'd always known what you're doing as a parameterised query...  that code you've pasted in is somewhat unreadable, if that's actually what you want to express, I'd suggest editing the question to include it

Comment: After doing research, it sounds like using PREPARE will create a prepared statement when i execute, and the leverage it in follow on executions by name.   Mmm.  It looks like this doesnt really exist in the realm of Psycopg2 from what I was looking into, and would have to write this all manually.